# How to identify controls while replay in 2nd IE instance in coded UI

Tags: coded-ui-tests

How to identify controls while replay in 2nd IE instance in coded UI.

I have recorded some assertions in a second IE instance, but coded UI is not passing the focus to the second IE instance while replay.

The scenario is like my report is generated in a new window. I have added some assertions to it. It gets saved properly. But when I replay it, coded UI never turns its focus on second IE, that is why my test fails.

Any help on this.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

First you actually need to distinguish the first and the second IE windows.
When launching them, store references for them somewhere, and then pass these instances as parent when finding controls.

In pseudocode:

```
// Open first and second window
var window1 = BrowserWindow.Launch("http://url1");
var window2 = BrowserWindow.Launch("http://url2");

// Do some work in window 1
var button = new HtmlButton(window1);
button.FilterProperties = blah-blah-blah
button.Click();

// Verify work in window 2
var label = new HtmlLabel(window2);
Assert.Equals("foo", label.Text);
```

Hope this gives you general idea.